# Combining foldl and foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I've figured out myself that `foldl` (or `foldl'`) is the best approach when you want to produce summarise a list into one result (i.e. `sum`), and `foldr` is the best approach when you want to produce another (perhaps even infinite) list (i.e. `filter`).

So I was considering was processing that combines these two. So I made the function `sum_f`. `sum_f` is fairly simple, all it does is add up the elements of a list, but if it finds an element such that `f x` is true, it gives the current result as output as the element of a list and starts summing from that point all over.

The code is here:

```
sum_f :: (Num a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
sum_f f = 
  let
    sum_f_worker s (x:xs) = 
      let
        rec_call z = sum_f_worker z xs
        next_sum = s + x
      in
        next_sum `seq` if (f x) then next_sum : (rec_call 0) else rec_call next_sum
    sum_f_worker _ [] = []
  in
    sum_f_worker 0
```

Now for example, lets sum all the positive integers grouped by any powers of two. This should output the following:

```
[1, 2, 3+4, 5+6+7+8, 9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16, ...]
```

i.e.

```
[1, 2, 7, 26, 100, ...]
```

We can do this like the following:

```
import Data.Bits

main = 
  let
    power_of_two x = (x .&. (x - 1)) == 0 -- .&. is bitwise and
  in
    print $ take 25 $ sum_f power_of_two [(1::Integer)..]
```

Now this above function (I believe) runs in constant space (like `foldl'`), even though the groups grow exponentially. Also, it works on infinite lists (like `foldr`).

I was wondering whether I could write the above using prelude functions without explicit recursion (i.e. only the recursion inside prelude functions). Or does combining the ideas of `foldl` and `foldr` here mean that the recursion here can't be done with standard prelude functions and needs to be explicit?

Comment: A good resource for understanding fold is the article ["A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf) by Graham Hutton.

Comment: @jug: I realise that foldl doesn't run in constant space, but foldl' does if you're careful about the strictness. I've edited the question to replace foldl with fold'.

Comment: A bit of a hack: `map sum $ groupBy (\_ y -> not (power_of_two (y-1))) [1..]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want can be expressed using only a right fold as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

sum_f :: (Num a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
sum_f p xs = foldr g (const []) xs 0
  where
    g x f !a = if p x then x+a:f 0 else f (x+a)

Prelude Data.Bits> sum_f (\x -> x .&. pred x == 0) [1..10]
[1,2,7,26]
```

And it works on infinite lists:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> take 10 . sum_f (\x -> x .&. pred x == 0) $ [1..]
[1,2,7,26,100,392,1552,6176,24640,98432]
```